# why are there two snap folders for chromium?

Tags: chromium, snap

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 19.10 where chromium was relocated into a snap image. Now there are two folders with exactly the same size:

```
$ du -shc /snap/chromium/*
574M    /snap/chromium/920
574M    /snap/chromium/937
0       /snap/chromium/current
1,2G    total
```

snap only lists the 937:

```
$ snap list chromium
Name      Version       Rev  Tracking  Publisher   Notes
chromium  78.0.3904.97  937  stable    canonical✓  -
```

How can I safely remove the old one? (Or are those hardlinked anyway, so I wouldn't gain any diskspace?)

Comment: Use `snap list`. Different versions... 920 and 937. And yes, you can `snap remove` to remove one of them. `man snap` for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `snap list --all` to list all versions including old ones. Old versions will be listed as "disabled"
2. You can use `snap remove chromium --revision=920` to remove the old one.
3. You could use the following script to remove all old snaps.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Removes old revisions of snaps
   # CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS
   set -eu

   LANG=C snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
       while read snapname revision; do
           snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
       done
   ```

Or, just ignore it since snap will only keep the 3 most recent versions.

Comment: Thanks, I could add a cronjob for this, or isn't there a config option for snap, that would keep only one version?

Comment: @rubo77 And if that one version has an unrecoverable problem?

Comment: Then I have an external backup ;)

Comment: you need sudo to remove the images: `LANG=C snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |     while read snapname revision; do        sudo snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision";     done
`